# Native vs. Non-native application development in Sybase Unwired Platform?

Tags: blackberry, sybase

I'm new to mobile application development using Sybase Unwired Platform. Can someone please tell me:

1. What is a native mobile application as compared to non-native mobile application in SUP?
2. What all types of Non-native applications can one develop in Sybase Unwired Platform (SUP)?

Answer (score 0):

The non native applications are called hybrid web container apps in sybase unwired platform.
These types of apps are used for decision making example: To approve or reject the purchase order. These apps doesn't need any coding, once developed it will work in all mobile platforms (Android, ios, windows and BB).

If the requirement is high in the sense if we want to do more with app we can choose native apps. It can be developed in two steps.
1. Develop project in sybase unwired platform
2. Native app development(Android,ios,windows and BB) that consumes the code generated by the sybase unwired platform.